# Why is my HLSL shader unable to compile to SPIRV?

Tags: c++, vulkan, hlsl, spir-v, dxc

In an update to my [last post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76985692/is-it-possible-to-compile-hlsl-shaders-to-spirv-using-the-visual-studio-hlsl-com) about compiling HLSL files directly through Visual Studio, I finally gave up and decided to use the offline compilation method instead. I was able to compile both of my HLSL shaders into `.spv` files, but now I am getting the following validation error:

```
Validation Error: [ VUID-VkShaderModuleCreateInfo-pCode-01379] 
Object 0: handle = 0x1c63c99aa70, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DEVICE; 
| MessageID = 0x2a1bf17f |
SPIR-V module not valid: Invalid SPIR-V magic number. The Vulkan spec states: 
If pCode is a pointer to GLSL code, it must be valid GLSL code written to the GL_KHR_vulkan_glsl GLSL extension specification
(https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.3.250.1/windows/1.3-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-VkShaderModuleCreateInfo-pCode-01379)
```

Unfortunately, the `.spv` file was compiled from HLSL code, so I'm not sure what the problem could be here.

These are the commands that I used when compiling the `.hlsl` files:

```
dxc.exe -spirv -T vs_6_4 -E main .\vertex_vert.hlsl -Fo .\vertex_vert.spv
dxc.exe -spirv -T ps_6_4 -E main .\pixel_frag.hlsl -Fo .\pixel_frag.spv
```

This is the contents of the vertex shader:

```
struct VSInput
{
    [[vk::location(0)]] float4 Position : POSITION0;
    [[vk::location(1)]] float4 Color : COLOR0;
    [[vk::location(2)]] float2 UVcoord : TEXCOORD0;
};
struct VSOutput
{
    float4 Position : SV_POSITION;
    [[vk::location(0)]] float4 Color : COLOR0;
    [[vk::location(1)]] float2 UVcoord : TEXCOORD0;
};
struct Camera
{
    float4x4 view;
    float4x4 proj;
    float3 position;
};
struct UBO
{
    float dt;
    float4x4 model;
    Camera cam;
};
/* neither of the below options changed the outcome */
//cbuffer ubo : register(b0, space0);
//{ UBO ubo; }
ConstantBuffer <UBO> ubo : register(b0, space0);

VSOutput main(VSInput input, uint VertexIndex : SV_VertexID)
{
    VSOutput output = (VSOutput) 0;
    
    float4x4 camMatrix = mul(ubo.cam.proj, ubo.cam.view);
    output.Position = mul(camMatrix, mul(ubo.model, input.Position));
    
    output.Color = input.Color;
    output.UVcoord = input.UVcoord;
    
    return output;
}
```

and this is the pixel/fragment shader HLSL code:

```
struct PSInput
{
    float4 Position : SV_Position;
    [[vk::location(0)]] float4 Color : COLOR0;
    [[vk::location(1)]] float2 UVcoord : TEXCOORD0;
};

// Descriptor loading in HLSL
//Texture2D tex2D : register(t0); // TODO: Figure out texture loading and sampling in HLSL
//sampler sample2D : register(s0, space1); // texture sampler at (binding = 0, set = 1)

struct PSOutput
{
    [[vk::location(0)]] float4 Color : COLOR0;
};

PSOutput main(PSInput input) : SV_TARGET
{
    PSOutput output = (PSOutput) 0;
    //output.Color = tex2D.Sample(sample2D, input.UVcoord); //TODO: figure out the right syntax for this
    output.Color = input.Color;
    return output;
}
```

and finally my shader struct:

```
struct Shader {
    Shader(const std::string& filename, VkShaderStageFlagBits shaderStage) {
        try {
            auto shaderCode = readFile(".\\shaders\\" + filename);
            createShaderModule(shaderCode, filename);
        }
        catch (const std::exception& e) {
                std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
            }
        stageInfo.stage = shaderStage;
        stageInfo.module = shaderModule;
        stageInfo.pName = "main";
    }
    ~Shader() {
        vkDestroyShaderModule(GPU::device, shaderModule, nullptr);
    }
public:
    VkShaderModule shaderModule;
    VkPipelineShaderStageCreateInfo stageInfo
    { VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_SHADER_STAGE_CREATE_INFO };
private:
    void createShaderModule(const std::vector<char>& code, std::string filename) {
        VkShaderModuleCreateInfo createInfo
        { VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SHADER_MODULE_CREATE_INFO };
        createInfo.codeSize = code.size();// also tried code.size()*sizeof(uint32_t) and code.size()*4
        createInfo.pCode = reinterpret_cast<const uint32_t*>(code.data());

        if (vkCreateShaderModule(GPU::device, &createInfo, nullptr, &shaderModule) != VK_SUCCESS) {
            throw std::runtime_error("failed to create shader module from " + filename + "!");
        }
    }
    // File Reader
    static std::vector<char> readFile(const std::string& filename) {
        std::ifstream file(filename, std::ios::ate | std::ios::binary);

        if (!file.is_open()) {
            throw std::runtime_error(std::format("failed to open {}!", filename));
        }

        size_t fileSize = (size_t)file.tellg();
        std::vector<char> buffer(fileSize);

        file.seekg(0);
        file.read(buffer.data(), fileSize);

        file.close();

        return buffer;
    }
};
```

The shaders are created with:

```
Shader vertShader("vertex_vert.spv", VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT);
Shader fragShader("pixel_frag.spv", VK_SHADER_STAGE_FRAGMENT_BIT);
```

I know my pixel/fragment shader will have some problems because I have yet to do the texture loading on the C++ side of things, but the vertex shader still produces the validation error even without the pixel shader. How can I fix this?

Edit: Changed the section containing the shader module function to show all of the code behind shader loading, most of which has been sourced from the [Vulkan-Tutorial](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Drawing_a_triangle/Graphics_pipeline_basics/Shader_modules) guide.

Edit 2:
I'm not sure which variable to look at after running the debugger, but here are a few that I believe are of interest:

When run with `code.size() * uint32_t`, the value of `createInfo.pCode` is `0x000001c2da20ff60` or `119734787` and the value of `code` is

```
\x3\x2#\a\0\0\x1\0\0\0\xe\0*\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\x11\0\x2\0\x1\0\0\0\xe\0\x3\0\0\0\0\0\x1\0\0\0\xf\0\v\0\0\0\0\0\x1\0\0\0main\0\0\0\0\x2\0\0\0\x3\0\0\0\x4\0\0\0\x5\0\0\0\x6\0\0\0\a\0\0\0\x3\0\x3\0\x5\0\0\0€\x2\0\0\x5\0\x5\0\b\0\0\0type.ubo\0\0\0\0\x6\0\x4\0\b\0\0\0\0\0\0\0ubo\0\x5\0\x3\0\t\0\0\0UBO\0\x6\0\x4\0\t\0\0\0\0\0\0\0dt\0\0\x6\0\x5\0\t\0\0\0\x1\0\0\0model\0\0\0\x6\0\x4\0\t\0\0\0\x2\0\0\0cam\0\x5\0\x4\0...
```

When run with `code.size()`, the value of `createInfo.pCode` is `0x00000196624fff60` or `119734787` and the value of `code` is

```
\x3\x2#\a\0\0\x1\0\0\0\xe\0*\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\x11\0\x2\0\x1\0\0\0\xe\0\x3\0\0\0\0\0\x1\0\0\0\xf\0\v\0\0\0\0\0\x1\0\0\0main\0\0\0\0\x2\0\0\0\x3\0\0\0\x4\0\0\0\x5\0\0\0\x6\0\0\0\a\0\0\0\x3\0\x3\0\x5\0\0\0€\x2\0\0\x5\0\x5\0\b\0\0\0type.ubo\0\0\0\0\x6\0\x4\0\b\0\0\0\0\0\0\0ubo\0\x5\0\x3\0\t\0\0\0UBO\0\x6\0\x4\0\t\0\0\0\0\0\0\0dt\0\0\x6\0\x5\0\t\0\0\0\x1\0\0\0model\0\0\0\x6\0\x4\0\t\0\0\0\x2\0\0\0cam\0\x5\0\x4\0...
```

Comment: If DXC didn't report any error, the shader is already compiled fine. So your problem is not in the compilation step, but rather the loading step. The help you with that, we need to see how you atually load the data you pass into `createShaderModule`-

Comment: @SaschaWillems I appreciate you taking a look at my code. I updated the shader module section to contain the full struct underlying shader creation.

Comment: Your shader loading code looks OK.  I even ran it to load your shaders and it worked fine.  And I changed the first word of the shader code to zero to make sure I then got the expected error.  So there's a disconnect between what you've posted and what is happening on your machine.  I'd suggest stopping in the debugger right before the call to `vkCreateShaderModule` to see if the first 32-bit word is the SPIR-V Magic Number.

Comment: @KarlSchultz I just updated the post with some additional information from the debugger. I'm not sure if these are the variables you'd like to see, so please let me know if they are not.  Could the problem be with the call to `reinterpret_cast` or is it possible that I need to get an updated version of `DXC`?  I am using the version that is selected for use by the command line input. I'm not sure if it is some standard VS one or the one in the VulkanSDK files. It is certainly not [this one](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXShaderCompiler) because I have not explicitly downloaded that one.

Comment: You want to look at the first 32-bit word of the SPIR-V code.  (SPIR-V binary is a list of 32-bit unsigned ints).  Try adding something like `uint32_t magic = createInfo.pCode[0];` after the line where you set the `pCode` pointer.  Then print it out or stop after that line in the debugger and check to see if its value is `0x07230203`.  The point of all this is to make sure that you are reading the SPIR-V binary code into memory properly.  The layer is checking for this magic value in the first word.

Comment: I'm getting `createInfo.pCode[0] = 0x000001e4974cff60 {119734787}`  when using `code.size()` and `createInfo.pCode = 0x000002aab9b8ff60 {119734787}` with `code.size() * sizeof(uint32_t)`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, you did show the contents at `pCode[0]` as 119,734,787 which is `0x07230203`, which is the correct magic number.  So I don't really know what's wrong.  Is there any chance that you're creating shader modules someplace else in the application and the validation errors are coming from there?

Comment: No chance. I boiled down my program to a single shader test environment. Is there a way to figure out which object is referred to by the `Object 0: handle = 0x1c63c99aa70` part of the validation layer error? That might help track down the culprit, but I am not expecting to find anything interesting.

Comment: Both shader look and compile fine ([vertex](https://shader-playground.timjones.io/3150c51ec52fd3ff2de8354249529b4a), [pixel](https://shader-playground.timjones.io/a0a92ec4eac6523ceff0a1541aa66f96)). Are you sure these shaders are the culprits or that your problem is with that _exact_ code on the C++ side?

Comment: That "Object 0" object is just the Device.  There's not a lot going on here and there are no other objects involved.  If you have a "single shader test environment", then perhaps you could post ALL of the code that actually generates the message to someplace like GitHub.  Since the shader code looks OK just prior to the call to create the module, I can only guess that the memory holding the code is getting stomped on during the call.  This suggests something going out of scope, but I don't think the code you posted suffers from that problem.

Comment: Here is the git repository for the test https://github.com/HeyoItsMateo/hlsl_test.git

Comment: The *.spv files checked into the repo have the incorrect contents.  Perhaps they were added to the repo without identifying them as binary and they got mangled as they were added to the repo. However it happened, the *.spv files have junk in them, along with the wrong magic number in the first word.  I don't know when you tested this relative to the check in.  I rebuilt the *.spv files with the dxc command you mentioned here.  Then the layer crashed because the size of the module was multiplied by 4.  This is not needed.  After removing this, the code ran for me without a validation error.

Comment: Thank you so much for all of your help. I was able to get the HLSL file to compile finally. It turns out that the "HLSL Compiler" was indeed the problem since it was overwriting the *.spv files that I had compiled through the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem here is that your Visual Studio project is using the "HLSL Compiler" settings to compile the shaders.  The `*.spv` files in the GitHub are OK (I was wrong about that in the long comment thread).  When you build the solution, Visual Studio is invoking the MSFT compiler which probably doesn't know about spirv.  Building the solution causes the `*.spv` files to get overwritten with incorrect contents.

I think the best way to fix this is to not use the "HLSL Compiler" build step in your project properties since this isn't a DX app.  Instead use a Custom Build Step to invoke the `dxc` compiler from the Vulkan SDK.